# Como recuperar os dados de uma página

Tags: php, regex

Boa tarde, alguém poderia me ajudar em como eu poderia recuperar os dados dessa página com php? [www.boline.com.br/teste.php](http://www.boline.com.br/teste.php)

Sei que precisa usar expressões regulares para poder separar os dados, mas não sei como fazer.

Comment: Que dados sao esses? Seria interessante você exemplicar com uma linha, como quer que separe.

Comment: Se eu entendi bem, seu link é mera cópia daqui, confirma?: http://www.netsorte.com.br/resultado_exportado/ResultadosMS.con Aqui tá muito mais fácil de pegar, pois não tem cabeçalhos nem nada, só as linhas. Basta usar o `explode` do PHP e o resultado sai pronto.

Answer (score 1):

Não necessariamente precise de regex para isso, pode ir fazendo explodes e obtendo os dados.

por exemplo, pode pegar todos os dados separados por espaço:

```
 $dados = explode("\n", file_get_contents('www.boline.com.br/teste.php'));
```

Ai pode ir iterando esse resultado e fazendo novos explodes ;)

Com regex:

```
preg_match_all('~([0-9]{4})=([0-9]{2}),([0-9]{2}),([0-9]{2}),([0-9]{2}),([0-9]{2}),([0-9]{2})~', file_get_contents('www.boline.com.br/teste.php'), $dados);
```

Ai você vai ter :

```
0001=41,05,04,52,30,33

$dados[1][0] = 0001
$dados[1][1] = 41
$dados[1][2] = 05
$dados[1][3] = 04
$dados[1][4] = 52
$dados[1][5] = 30
$dados[1][6] = 33
```

Comment: Nesse caso, como se trata de um conteúde possivelmente de terceiro, quanto de memória ele vai utilizar? A melhor solução é quebrando 1 vez com explode os espaços e depois utilizar Generator para parsear o resto, como não sei a versão do php do nosso amigo, dei apenas duas opções